# React-Router with Fetch Causing 404 (Not Found)

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, react-router, http-status-code-404

I am writing a program that uses spring-boot (with maven) and a PostgreSQL database in the backend, and react js in the frontend.

Initially, I had a test.js file representing a single web page that created a fetch request to talk the backend controller that, in turn, updated the database. This worked, so I wanted to take it a step further using react-router to link more than one page on the frontend. However, when I tried to implement the react-router, it caused my initial fetch requests to return 404 (Not Found).

Here is an example of one of the fetch requests in my new test.js file.

```
const line = {
    name: this.state.name,
    id: this.state.id
};
const fetchOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept' : 'application/json',
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*'
    },
    body : JSON.stringify(line)
};

let url = "/create";
console.log("creating");
fetch(url, fetchOptions)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(message => {
         this.setState({message: message.text})
    })
    .catch((error) => {
         console.log("error: ", error.message);
    })
```

This is my main.js code that implements react-router:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Route,
  NavLink,
  Switch,
  HashRouter
} from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Home";
import Test from "./Test";

class Main extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <HashRouter>
        <div>
          <h1>Simple SPA</h1>
          <ul className="header">
            <li><NavLink to="/">Home</NavLink></li>
            <li><NavLink to="/Test">Test</NavLink></li>

          </ul>
          <Switch className="content">
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
            <Route path="/Test" component={Test}/>
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </HashRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default Main;
```

Last, here is a look at how the controller receives the request:

```
@PostMapping("/create")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseTransfer createTransfer(@RequestBody String student) {
    // Code to update database
    ...
    return new ResponseTransfer(student);
}
```

To reiterate: the basic idea here is that there is a Home page and a Test page linked through react-router. The Test page has a text field and a button that allows the user to "create" an entry in the database. The problem is that when the user clicks "create," a fetch request is made to "/create" in the Test.js file. However, it is not reaching the @PostMapping("/create") in the backend controller, and instead is just getting a 404 (Not Found). Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: if you are getting a 404 means that you are hitting the backend server, and the spring application is answering back 404 Not Found, so i suggest you use the debugger in chrome to see what the exact address your frontend is calling and then see if it matches the correct address.

Comment: is the spring app serving the react application or are they run independently from each other.  react app is localhost:3000, spring app is localhost:8080?

Comment: Yes, I verified that both addresses are "localhost:3000/create." The spring app (localhost:8080) and the react app (localhost:3000) are running independently from each other. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As figured out in the comments.

When running a react application, independently using say `npm start` or `yarn start` it will start per default using node and serve the application on localhost:3000.

A spring boot application will be run default using localhost:8080.

The front end (react application) will also per default assume that the host of all rest calls is the same as the running application (localhost:3000). So if you would make a rest call to say "/create" it would end up doing it against `localhost:3000/create` and that would end up as a 404 since we are not even touching the spring boot service, we are hitting the node server that doesn\t have that endpoint.

there are several ways of solving it. One way is to serve the react application from the spring boot application, this will make the react app to have the same hostname as the spring boot service.

Another quick fix is to add `"proxy": "http://localhost:8080"` in your package.json to proxy all requests to the correct hostname.

you can read more about proxying [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/)

Several different ways all depending on how you want to solve it.